# Grouped bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to replicate this graph (with faceting between groups)
[image: barplot]
(facetting as done in)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXvJB.png)
This is my try:

```
library (ggplot2)
data<- data.frame(
  d = rep(LETTERS[21:26], 10),
  val = rnorm (60),
  c = rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 6)
)

ggplot(data, aes(c, val)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = val), position = "dodge") +
 facet_grid(data[, 1] ~ .)
```

and graphs are arranged vertically instead of the dodged position. What should I do?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need `facet_grid()`, just fill by `'d'`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(c, val)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = d), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

---

As per OP's comment we can also use `facet_grid(cols = vars(d))`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(c, val)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = val), position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(d)) # or facet_grid(. ~ d)
```

[image]

Comment: I need horizontal facetting, which I coudnt reproduce in  excel.

Comment: @biofan Edited my answer. Hope this helps.